# PHP simplexml_load_file -> parsing a php-file with XML-Header

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've a php-file like this (pseudo.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo "<mycontainer>";
echo "<foo>bar</foo>";
echo "</mycontainer>";
?>
```

If I open this file in a Webbrowser I get the well formed XML-Content and also the W3C-Validation confirms well formed XML.
But it's not possible to parse this file with *simplexml_load_file*:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("pseudo.php");
```

returns:

```
parser error : Start tag expected
```

is there a workaround or such like? Thanx for your help.

Comment: You are accessing the PHP file's contents, not what is rendered.

Comment: you should not create XML by concatenating strings your own... . instead use an XML library that handles XML creation. PHP ships with a few of those out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (replace pseudo.php with the correct URL with `http://...`):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string("http://your.example.com/pseudo.php");
```

Comment: @hellcode: The HTTP wrapper works with `simplexml_load_string` already, no need for `file_get_contents`. just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the file through PHP somehow; when you directly load it from disk, you are getting `<?php` as part of the file content, instead of it being a processing directive for the PHP engine.

Alternatively, just remove the PHP code from the file entirely, and make it a proper XML file.